# Ember design pattern

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a project based on ember, but I'm unsure about the design.
I have an application controller that all the other controllers are extending:

Base controller

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs:['userNav'],
    dateNavSelected : '',
    currentSleeperImg:AppStateManager.get('currentSleeperImg'),
    currentSleeperName:AppStateManager.get('currentSleeperName'),        
    didSleeperChange:false,
    logout: function(){
        AppStateManager.transitionTo('loggedOutState');
        this.transitionToRoute('signin');
    },
    selectSleeper: function(sleeper){ //Gets the sleeper change from the menu
        var currSleeper = AppStateManager.get('currentSleeperObj');
        if(!currSleeper || (currSleeper && sleeper.get('id') != currSleeper.get('id'))){
            AppStateManager.set('currentSleeperImg', sleeper.get('sleeper_avatar'));
            AppStateManager.set('currentSleeperName', sleeper.get('sleeper_name'));
            AppStateManager.set('currentSleeperObj', sleeper );
            this.set('currentSleeperImg' , sleeper.get('sleeper_avatar'));
            this.set('currentSleeperName' , sleeper.get('sleeper_name'));
            this.set('didSleeperChange', true);
        }else{
            this.set('didSleeperChange', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Child controller

```
App.LastNightSummaryController = App.ApplicationController.extend({        
    pageTitle: moment().subtract('days', 1).format("MMM D"),
    active:'last-night-summary',        
    selectSleeper: function(sleeper){ //Gets the sleeper change from the menu
        this._super(sleeper);   
        if(this.get('didSleeperChange')){
            this.set('content', App.SleepData.find({id:sleeper.get('id'), sleeper:sleeper}));
        }    
    }    
});
```

Is a good pattern?

Comment: IMO a Strict NO to extend applicationController for every Controller... The properties that should be handled in application level should be placed there... Every other entities should have their own Controller to handle that specific state...

Comment: I usually do something similar to this, but not with the `ApplicationController` of course. You could do something like this, but extend `ObjectController` and `ArrayController` instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should be extending from the base controllers. The application controller already has the responsibility of keeping track of application state. If you need to reach the application controller for any reason, use @controllerFor("application") in your code.